# How to access a downloaded internal-file icon and use as a drawable e.g. in setIcon(drawable)

Tags: android

I download a png icon and store it on the internal file system.
How can I use this icon in a similar manner to a drawable in res/drawable.
I can read it and pulls its ears, but how to use it in a setIcon() method?
Does an internal file have a resource id? (wishful thinking).

I notice someone suggest saving to res/raw, but you cant write to application folders anyway.

I've been using:  *openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);*
But maybe I need to create a File object and do the usual Java stuff. Even so,
how to grab it as a drawable in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) in your case.

Comment: I've already downloaded the icon as a bitmap but I dont have access to the ImageView of the icon I want to replace. I cant dump the bitmap on any ImageView - unless you can show me how to find the imageview of a Logo in the ActionBar. Is there the obvious I'm missing here? setLogo(myBitmap) ??

Comment: Oh oh I see it for sure new BitmapDrawable(bitmap). Yummy

Comment: Note that this constructor is deprecated. Instead you should use BitmapDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap). The reseources object is needed to properly scalling.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Michal, that works a treat. This was the icing on the app cake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromStream(openFileInput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Then you can use that drawable in the ImageView with its setImageDrawable(drw); method

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer arcastro, it gives me the option of saving or caching the icon, then retrieving it later for speed.